# Button does not disappear again when the layout is touched

Tags: android, android-layout, timer

```
        final Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run (){
                try{
                    //sleep
                    sleep (2000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    nav2.setAnimation(alpha2);
                    nav2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start(); 

        nav1.setOnClickListener(new LinearLayout.OnClickListener(){

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 nav2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 nav2.setAnimation(inleft);
                 timer.start();

}});
```

I have a code that will make  button or linearlayout disappear after 2 secs in the timer the problem is that it crashes once the finally executes. Also the other button (nav1) is the whole linear layout so once it had been touched the nav2 or the buttons will appear and the timer will again reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead of thread,

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    nav2.setAnimation(alpha2);
                    nav2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 2000);
```

Comment: I love you men!HAHAHAHAHAHA now how can i rerun it again? the timer.start(); Sorry such a noob

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can't touch your UI widgets from a background thread.

For your use case, consider a `Handler` on the UI thread and a `Runnable` posted with `postDelayed()`.